# Hash Table Size of Array

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable

Quick question why is it better to have a hash table size twice the size as the input array? Why would I want a table size of 40 (if my array was size 20) not something closer or even 20?

Comment: The term of art you are looking for is [load factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Key_statistics). A load factor of 50% is on a low side; load around 80% is a more typical goal.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the collision method. If you have a perfect hash method then size 20 array is enough for 20 keys but in most cases there will be collisions and that means that they have to be placed at a new place in the array and finding that place can be difficult (sometimes impossible) if there is only one space left.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take precautions for collissions. Suppose the size is 20. And there are 20 values to place. If the hash function was not suitable for the data and all data was being directed to the last point that is 20, and there is no rollover measure in place, the data will be put in the next index i.e 21. If all the 20 data were to be mapped to this last index, you will need 20 more places. So for size of data n it is better to have size of hash table 2n